# can't find databases folder under data/data/packagename/ using eclipse android emulator

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

I'm having problem with sqlite android. According to examples that I found from internet, databases can be found under data/data/packagename/ but I can't find this folder under the directory.

Please tell me what's the problem?

And I provide my sqlitehelper class in case if it's necessary .

```
   package com.example.waterrefilltest;
  import static android.provider.BaseColumns._ID;



 import android.content.ContentValues;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


    public class data extends SQLiteOpenHelper{


private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "waterrefill.db";

public data(Context ctx){
    super(ctx, DATABASE_NAME, null, 4);
}



public void generateData(Content c){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("lat", c.getLat());
    cv.put("long", c.getLng());
    cv.put("cat",c.getCt());
    cv.put("rat", c.getRt());
    cv.put("ph",c.getPh());
    cv.put("distance", c.getDistance());
    db.insert("contents", null, cv);
    db.close();
}

public void deleteData(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE contents");

}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE contents ("+_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , lat TEXT ,  longi TEXT , cat TEXT , rat TEXT , ph TEXT , distance TEXT );");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contents");
    onCreate(db);



}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess databse is not created yet. thats why you are not able to see it. try this in your mainactivity class:

```
data dt = new data(this);
SQLiteDatabase db = dt.getReadableDatabase();
```

database is created when oncreate is called and when you call getReadAbleDatabase() its oncreate get called and database created

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not created, the cause **may** be the **";"** you used in your create table **statement**.